# hover in jQuery increment fontSize error

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-animate, font-size

ok, I'm fooling around with jQuery and for the life of me can't find an elegant way to fix this error.

```
jQuery('a').hover(function()
{
    jQuery(this).animate({fontSize : '+=5'});
}, function()
{
    jQuery(this).animate({fontSize : '-=5'});
});
```

The problem with that is that I build up an animation que. I thought i could solve it with stop() like this:

```
jQuery('a').hover(function()
{
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({fontSize : '+=5'});
}, function()
{
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({fontSize : '-=5'});
});
```

But if you mouse over it and unmouse over it you lose a full 5px even though it didn't yet add 5 yet. Is there a way to reset the pixel size something like .css(fontSize, "") or computedStyle or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're almost there. you just need to use `.stop(true,true)`.

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TUxEt/)

<sub>Welcome to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)</sub>